Al intentar restaurar base de datos desde MySQL, los intentos de restauración aparecen en blanco
Estoy haciendo unos ejercicios de la escuela en los que tengo que hacer respaldos de las bases de datos; hasta ahí todo bien, pero al momento de restaurar ese respaldo me crea solamente la base de datos pero vacía. No sé si tenga mucho que ver, pero intenté hacer un usuario nuevo ya que el que tenía por defecto mi computadora tiene un espacio lo cual me causaba conflicto a la hora de hacer respaldos. Eso ya lo solucioné, pero ahora no sé si eso me haya afectado para restaurar respaldos porque todos los que he intentado restablecer aparecen en blanco.
Adjunto código de lo que estoy respaldando en símbolo del sistema.
mysqldump -u root -p escuela > C:\Users\GUS\respaldoescuela.sql


Y tu sql generado ademas de las tablas tiene los datos? recibis algun error??? y principalmente, esto no es un foro, es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas...

Si estas marcando las casillas que salen en la parte baja de la ventana, sino mal recuerdo cuando haces backups de la BD, las casillas indican lo que quieres respaldar como los datos, los procedimientos almacenados, y no recuerdo cual era la opción, o si eran esas opciones

Amigos muchas gracias por las recomendaciones, en general no conozco mucho el entorno y me sigo familiarizando con SQL pude resolver mi problema sin tanto detalle muchas gracias.

Que bien! Yo escribo muy lento y te escribi la mejor respuesta que pude, sin ver que habias resuelto el problema. Para evitar eso, es aconsejable marcar las respuestas como satisfactorias una vez resueltas.

Primero, recomiendo no usar root para tareas rutinarias como esta. Es una buena práctica crear un usuario con permisos específicos para manejar la base de datos que estás trabajando.

Estoy asumiendo que el usuario es estudiante
La contraseña es C0ntrasen@
Y el servido es localhost

Aquí dejo el código completo para crear un usuario (sin espacios blancos) y asignarle los permisos adecuados:
Entrar en el servidor db:
mysql -u root -p

Crear un nuevo usuario con contraseña:
CREATE USER 'estudiante'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'C0ntrasen@';

Otorgar permisos globales al usuario (opcional):
GRANT ALL ON . TO 'estudiante'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'C0ntrasen@';

Este paso otorga permisos globales al usuario, pero es recomendable otorgar permisos solo a la base de datos específica.
Crear la base de datos:
CREATE DATABASE escuela;

Asignar permisos sobre la base de datos específica:
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON escuela.* TO 'estudiante'@'localhost';

Aquí limitamos los permisos del usuario estudiante solo a la base de datos escuela, lo cual es más seguro.
Actualizar los privilegios:
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Restauración de la base de datos:
Luego de configurar el usuario, puedes restaurar la base de datos usando este comando desde la terminal:
mysql -u estudiante -p escuela < C:\Users\GUS\respaldoescuela.sql

Con esto se debería poder restaurar la base de datos incluyendo todas las tablas y datos.
